# Python: How can I find the heading of the road using Google Maps API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I wrote a program in python that takes in a starting point and end point and then uses google maps API to create a gif of the route using google street view. Everything works perfectly I just can't find a way to get the bearing/heading of the car. The resulting gifs is the correct path but the camera doesn't point at the road.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b17el2lmiyna7m6/finalproduct8fps.gif?dl=0

here is sample to show you what I mean, the camera isn't pointing at the road at all times, how can I get the heading of the vehicle?

Comment: Found a solution. https://gist.github.com/jeromer/2005586. thanks to Allanon001 on reddit.